# Help with Converting Method to Async Method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, asynchronous, methods

I am trying to convert a method in my app to an async method. It is a method which loads a number of custom markers on Google Map view. I need to make this async so that the view displays instantly while the markers then load.

Can anyone help give me some pointers on how I can convert the below method to an async method ? I am struggling to understand the concept. Thank you.

```
private void showpins() throws IOException {

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

    Address = mCursor.getString(4);
    Name = mCursor.getString(0);


    String noSpaces = Address.replaceAll(" ", "+");

    JSONObject geocoded = getLocationInfo(noSpaces);
    GeoPoint point = getGeoPoint(geocoded);


    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    CustomizedItemOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
    new CustomizedItemOverlay(drawable, this);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = 
    new OverlayItem(point, Name, Address);

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the majority of the time spent in your method? Is it the `getLocationInfo` and `getGeoPoint` calls that take up most time or the `SQLiteDatabase` access?

Comment: Hi Paul. It would be in the getLocationInfo as this is where the JSON routine gets the location info from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what all the methods do that are called by the method you posted, but I'll assume that only the calls to mapOverlays affects the UI and that everything else can happen in the background. You can turn this into an AsyncTask like this (this would be best as an inner class, I think):

```
class OverlayLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, CustomizedItemOverlay, Void> {
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    @Override
    protected onPreExecute() {
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

            Address = mCursor.getString(4);
            Name = mCursor.getString(0);

            String noSpaces = Address.replaceAll(" ", "+");

            JSONObject geocoded = getLocationInfo(noSpaces);
            GeoPoint point = getGeoPoint(geocoded);

            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
            CustomizedItemOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
                new CustomizedItemOverlay(drawable, this);

            CustomizedItemOverlay overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, Name, Address);

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
            publishProgress(overlayitem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPublishProgress(CustomizedItemOverlay... overlayItem) {
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So do I delete out my showpins() method and replace it with the class above? Or do I create a new class file for this class ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco - Yes, you would eliminate the showpins() method and replace the call to showpins with `new OverlayLoader().execute();`.

Comment: I'm getting a few compiler errors on the last few lines of code :                 CustomizedItemOverlay overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, Name, Address);

                publishProgress(overlayitem);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPublishProgress(CustomizedItemOverlay... overlayItem) {
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        }
    }

Comment: 1) onPublishProgress cannot resolve itemized overlay 2) the method onPublish progress must override or implement a supertype method 3)Type mismatch - cannot convert from overlayitem to CustomizedItemOverlay.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco - Yeah, I screwed up the refactoring. I think I fixed it. Since you accepted it as the answer, maybe you got it working on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while back. However it had the problem of creating a new thread for each image therefore eventually crashing. This was necessary (kindof) for me but you should be able to do it without that if you are not getting the images from the internet. Here's the code-

```
/**
*
* @author Kyle
*/
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    populate();
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
    //---when user lifts his finger---
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ArrayList db = MainActivity.getDB(mContext);

                int i=0;

                for (Object o : db) {
                    if(i>40)break;

                    final ArrayList list = ((ArrayList) o);
                    final int lon = (int) ((Double.parseDouble("" + list.get(1)) * 1000000.0) + .5);
                    final int lat = (int) ((Double.parseDouble("" + list.get(2)) * 1000000.0) + .5);
                    final GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
                    if (isCurrentLocationVisible(mapView, point)) {
                        Log.i("***", "POINT IS VISIBLE");
                        if (mOverlays.size() > 40) {
                            i++;
                            Log.i("***", i+"");
                            removeOverlay(0);
                        }

                        if (lat != 0) {

                            Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "" + lat + " " + lon, list.get(0).toString().replace("jpg", "mjpg").replace("image", "video"));

                                    final String url = list.get(0).toString().replace("mjpg", "jpg").replace("video", "image");

                                    Drawable d = MainActivity.getImage(url);

                                    if (d != null) {
                                        d.setBounds(0, 0, 48, 32);
                                        overlayitem.setMarker(d);
                                        addOverlay(overlayitem);
                                        mapView.postInvalidate();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                            t.start();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("***", "POINT IS OUTSIDE VISIBLE RECT");
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
    return false;
}


public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public void removeOverlay(int index) {
    try {
        mOverlays.remove(index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("***", e.toString());
    }
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    return true;
}
}
```

and the main activity-

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

public static final String mapsApi = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "CamWorldPrefsFile";
ListView myListView = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cam);
    //   d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth()-50, d.getIntrinsicHeight());

    final HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                //myDbHelper.close();
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                String query = "SELECT * from database;";

                ArrayList stringList = myDbHelper.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
                myDbHelper.close();

                for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size() - 1; i++) {
                    final ArrayList list = (ArrayList) stringList.get(i);
                    try {
                        if (Double.parseDouble("" + list.get(1)) != 0) {
                            Log.i("***", list.get(0).toString().replace("mjpg", "jpg").replace("video", "image"));
                            //                    Log.i("***", list.get(2) + " : ");
                            //                    Log.i("***", list.get(3) + " : ");

                            final int lon = (int) ((Double.parseDouble("" + list.get(1)) * 1000000.0) + .5);
                            final int lat = (int) ((Double.parseDouble("" + list.get(2)) * 1000000.0) + .5);

                            final GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

                            if (lat != 0) {

                                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        final OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "" + lat + " " + lon, list.get(0).toString().replace("jpg", "mjpg").replace("image", "video"));

                                        final String url = list.get(0).toString().replace("mjpg", "jpg").replace("video", "image");

                                        Drawable d = MainActivity.getImage(url);

                                        if (d != null) {
                                            d.setBounds(0, 0, 48, 32);
                                            overlayitem.setMarker(d);
                                            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                                t.start();
                            }

                            // ("http://151cam.uoregon.edu/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=160x120")

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("***", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                //    mapView.invalidate();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
        }
    }).start();


    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```